# Hierarchical Looping

Tags: java, loops, hierarchical

I have a SQL table with data as follows.

[image]

I have a requirement to retrieve the program-calls(Right column) for  program-names as a LIST(ArrayList) .

Assuming that, I have to retrieve program-calls for program-name = A, the select returns back the results(program-calls) as follows..

```
B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
```

However, I will have to select on each of the program names to see if B has any calls... in that case, B returns ...

```
Z,Q,E,R,T
```

My list should add B's data --> `Z,Q,E,R,T,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I` . I added B's data to the final list ( Including B). I have to trickle down all the way until the and build a flat list.

For the program-name = A .

I am looking to get a result of something like this.

```
A,Z,L,Q,E,R,T,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
```

Here is the Code that I have written until now to retrieve the data and storing it in a list.

```
        String[] alTogetherString = null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    Session session  = null;
    HibernateUtil h1 = null;
    List<String> abendInfo = new ArrayList<String>();   
    String xmlStrings = "";
    // Configure the session factory
    h1 = new HibernateUtil();
    sessionFactory =  h1.buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Successfully connected");

    Map<String, List<String>> map3 = null;


    map3 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();


    Criteria crteria = session.createCriteria(Delays.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("programName", "A"));
    List<Delays> DelaysList = crteria.list();

    System.out.println(DelaysList.size());

    for(Delays d : DelaysList)
    {
        String alTogther = d.getProgramCalls();
        alTogetherString = alTogther.split(",");
    }

    // Create a list to put the first list of options...
    List<String> firstListOfOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String exd : alTogetherString)
    {
        firstListOfOptions.add(exd);
    }

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    sessionFactory.close();
```

Please help me through this hierarchical looping

Comment: Depth-first search. Have you tried that?

Comment: If you're on Postgres, you can use a recursive `CTE` to get the results easily.